# Why this loop does not iterate during second run?

Tags: c, loops

I am C novice and got stuck with the following problem. Can somebody explain what is wrong with the loop to count interest and a sum? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*simple interest rate calculator */

int main()
{
    int year, y;
    float sum, interest, i; // i = interest after iteration
    y = 0; 
    i = 0;

    printf("Provide a sum you want to invest(in pence):\n");
    scanf("%f", &sum);
    printf("Provide interest rate:\n");
    scanf("%f", &interest);
    printf("For how long would you like to save(in years):\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);

    /*for(y = 1; y <= year; y++)
    i = sum * interest/100;
    sum += i; */ 

    do
    {   
      i = sum * interest/100;
      sum += i;
    }   
    while (y == 1 && y<= year);

    printf("Original sum %0.0f at %0.1f rate for %d years:\n\n", sum,    interest, year);
    printf("   Year  Interest  Sum\n");
    printf("--------+--------+--------\n");
   for(y = 1; y<= year; y++)
       printf("%5d %11.2f %5.2f\n", y, i, sum);

   return 0;

  }
```

The output is:
Original sum 33750 at 12.5 rate for 10 years:

Year  Interest  Sum
--------+--------+--------
    1     3750.00 33750.00
    2     3750.00 33750.00
    3     3750.00 33750.00
    4     3750.00 33750.00
    5     3750.00 33750.00
    6     3750.00 33750.00
    7     3750.00 33750.00
    8     3750.00 33750.00
    9     3750.00 33750.00
   10     3750.00 33750.00

and with every line it should take a new sum and calculate accordingly.

Thanks very much for any hints.

Comment: `y == 1 && y<= year` most likely does not what you expect. `year` must be 1 for the expression to be true.

Comment: and the value of  `y` doesn't change in the body of the loop.

Comment: I really did not get the flow of your program.

Answer (score 2):

```
 do
{   
  i = sum * interest/100;
  sum += i;
}   
while (y == 1 && y<= year);
```

In this loop value of `y` does not change therefore 2nd time condition is false as `y` is initialized as `0`.Thus values of `sum` remains same as it was after `1st` iteration. increment `y` in this loop and change condition to

```
while ( y<year);// y<year because y is initialized to 0
```

### EDIT

Didn't really understand why you used this loop -

```
for(y = 1; y<= year; y++)
printf("%5d %11.2f %5.2f\n", y, i, sum);
```

It will print same value in every iteration. If you want to print `interst` and `sum` value for every  year you should just use the `printf`  statement inside the above `while loop`.

Comment: Thanks very much, finally got it.

Answer (score 0):

your do while() loop only runs once, since one of the conditions is "y == 1" which will evaluate to false after you increment y, thus the loops stops.
You also don increment y anywhere and since it's initialized to 0 it also doesn't satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.

```
int y = 1;  // initialize with 1
printf("   Year  Interest  Sum\n");
printf("--------+--------+--------\n");
do
{   
    i = (sum * interest)/100; // it will calculate sum+interest for 1 year.
    sum += i;
    y++;
    printf("%5d %11.2f %5.2f\n", y, i, sum);
}   
while (y <= year);  // you can compare y > 0 also in case you kept y = 0
printf("Original sum %0.0f at %0.1f rate for %d years:\n\n", sum, interest, year);
```

Comment: Yes Himanshu, that's almost exactly what I did after I read above posts. Anyway thank you very much.